# Snowflake - setting up role for PII / masked data

Tags: sql, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please consider the below:

1. Role A can see masked fields as allowed by masking policy X.
2. I assign role A to role B who does not have permission to see masked fields as not allowed by masking policy X.

Question: Is role B now allowed to see masked fields as role A has now been granted to role B?

If the above is not possible what's the best way to set up a role that can see PII / masked fields if you have multiple roles in a Snowflake account and not all of them should see PII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not already using database roles then I'd strongly suggest you start as they make life much easier when setting up your RBAC model.

You need to separate your data access roles from your masking policy roles. The simplest model would be to have 2 database roles:

- One has SELECT privileges on the tables and views in the database; let's call it DB_RO
- The other is the one used in your masking policy definition; let's call it PI_ALL

You can now grant the DB_RO role to any role that needs to be able to select data from this database.

For any role that also needs to be able to see masked data in this database, you also grant it the PI_ALL role.

If, for some reason, you granted the PI_ALL role to a role that didn't also have the DB_RO role it would have no effect - as that role wouldn't be able to select any data in the database

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for this. What if user Mary has access to both roles DB_RO and PI_ALL. We now granted PI_ALL role to role DB_RO. PI_ALL can see PII according to our Masking Policy. Will Mary automatically be able to see PII data even when she has set the context to role DB_RO? Or she will need to set context to PI_ALL to see the PII data?

Comment: For a start, don't grant the PI_ALL role to the DB_RO role as that negates the point of creating the two separate roles in the first place. Roles are granted privileges; if you grant a role to a role (say grant roleA to roleB) then roleB has the privileges granted directly to it and also inherits the privileges granted to roleA. A user has the privileges granted to the role it's using (including any inherited privileges); additionally, with the use of SECONDARY ROLES, a user has all the privileges granted to all the roles granted to the user

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I will go with secondary roles as I think this is the simplest solution. Do you need to run "use secondary roles all" everytime you want to use secondary roles? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. I only mentioned secondary roles for completeness when explaining generically how roles work in Snowflake. I'm not sure how they would be relevant to your specific scenario and therefore it's possibly you haven't understood. However, as this is turning into a discussion, feel free to implement what you want and, if you still have issues, you can raise another question.

Comment: Well I thought secondary role could be a solution as in my example above granting role A to B whilst testing didn't allow the user with role B to see PII masked fields.